# Mixed effect model in python

Tags: python, statistics, regression, statsmodels

Hi i have a certain task i want to solve:

i have this task:

For two months, participants played an app, in which they played 5 different
therapeutic games (TGs). At the beginning of each session, they also completed a
5-scale State-of-Mind questionnaire, rating the extent to which they feel tired (or
rested), distracted (or focused), cautious (or adventurous), sad (or happy), and
hungry (or full). Scores range from -1 to 1.

Leverage playing data (time & levels played in each TG in each session) to
predict/model changes in the participant’s state of mind

and a data set which contains these columns:
Index(['Participant #', 'date', 'time_tg1', 'time_tg2', 'time_tg3', 'time_tg4',
'time_tg5', 'levels_tg1', 'levels_tg2', 'levels_tg3', 'levels_tg4',
'levels_tg5', 'rested', 'focused', 'adventaurous', 'happy', 'full',
'day of use']

I am not sure regarding the level columns if they are categorial or not.

after centering and removing outliers i tried with rpy2 in order to add 2 random effects (participant + day of use):

model_formula <- 'happy ~ time_tg1 + C(levels_tg1)+time_tg1:C(levels_tg1)+ time_tg2 + C(levels_tg2) + time_tg2:C(levels_tg2)+ time_tg3 +C(levels_tg3) + time_tg3:C(levels_tg3)+ time_tg4 + C(levels_tg4)+time_tg4:C(levels_tg4)+time_tg5 +C(levels_tg5)+time_tg5:C(levels_tg5)+(1|Participant_) + (1|day_of_use)

```
i am really not sure if this is the correct way or not?
```

Comment: Do you want a solution to the errors you are facing? How to model non-ordinal categorical variables? What is the exact question here ?

Comment: Thank you for your response
Actually i am a bit confused. i succeeded with fixing all the errors and i am a bit unsure how to continue.
i dont really know if the levels are categorial or not. and there is another variable i think i should insert into the model which is day of use.
i am not really sure how to build the model and what should be the fixed/random effects here

Comment: here is my current try (which i did with rpy2):
        model_formula <- 'happy ~ time_tg1 + C(levels_tg1)+time_tg1:C(levels_tg1)+  time_tg2 + C(levels_tg2) + time_tg2:C(levels_tg2)+ time_tg3 +C(levels_tg3) + time_tg3:C(levels_tg3)+
           time_tg4 + C(levels_tg4)+time_tg4:C(levels_tg4)+time_tg5 +C(levels_tg5)+time_tg5:C(levels_tg5)+(1|Participant_) + (1|day_of_use) '